# Ubuntu 20.04 & KILLER Wi-Fi 6 AX1650 + BLUETOOTH 5.1

Tags: 20.04

did anybody run this card KILLER Wi-Fi 6 AX1650 + BLUETOOTH 5.1 on Ubuntu ?
I have Dell M4800 and want to upgrade my WIFI and BT.

Comment: The best way to know is to try running Ubuntu from a live USB, which won't affect your system otherwise.

Comment: The thing is that I need to now if it works before I buy it